# Streaming Server Implementation based on Embedded Camera board

Tags: networking

I've developed a camera which works with z-board & Ubuntu Linux. 
Video streaming is working between camera  server and PC client GUI with ethernet, which is TCP/IP networking.

Moreover, I'm on process to implement Web server to stream the data via internet.
To stream video from Camera to Web or App, which network protocol is required?
I've heard RTP protocol, but don't know the details.